# Reading postgres tables in terminal with java

Tags: java, linux, postgresql, terminal

Iḿ trying to build an application which collect all tables in my postgres db, by java code.

```
        Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su - postgres -c \"psql -p 8080 -l -t | awk '! (/^ / || /^ foo/ || /^ bar/) {print \\$1}'\"");
```

I filtered out some tables in the code (foo, bar) and I only want to collect table names.

This command runs without error in terminal, directly, but doesnt work by my application!

Complete Code:

```
  Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su - postgres -c \"psql -p 8080 -l -t | awk '! (/^ / || /^ foo/ || /^ bar/) {print \\$1}'\"");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(p1.getInputStream()));

String line = null;
String result = "";
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    result +=  line;
}
```

I've got no errors... But the result string is null

Someone who can help me out?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why don't you connect to Postgres directly and get tables names from the system catalog? This approach looks cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have double quotes within the exec, as Java does will not interpret it correctly. Try it like so, using this version of [Runtime.exec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])):

```
 String[] myCommand = new String[] {"su", "- postgres", "-c" , "psql -p 8080 -l -t | awk '! (/^ / || /^ foo/ || /^ bar/) {print \\$1}" };
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(myCommand);
```